# Adding style attribute to SVG path with D3 in Chromium based browsers does not work

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

Selecting a `<path>` element inside an `<svg>` element with D3:

```
d3.select("#my_id").style("fill", "red");
```

has no effect in Chromium based browsers. This works perfectly fine in Firefox 70. The only way I can add the style attribute to the `<path>` element in Chromium browsers is on its creation.

I've also attempted adding it as an attribute, which works in Firefox, but I know this is not strictly valid since the `<svg>` and `<path>` elements don't have a "fill" attribute:

```
d3.seelect("#my_id").attr("fill", "red");
```

Comment: svg and path elements do have a fill attribute, having said that, you should report the former problem to chrome's bugtracker.

Comment: Your question makes little sense to me: I'm a D3 programer and your first snippet works in all Chromium-based browsers. Please try to create a [MCVE] that doesn't work for you, so we can check.